# A UK scammer frauded money from US victim

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, united-kingdom, international, fraud

Could this US victim accuse this UK scammer? Since uk and us has different legislations, how should the victim accuse the scammer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this US victim accuse this UK scammer?

Yes

> Since uk and us has different legislations, how should the victim accuse the scammer?

1. Report the scam to the relevant US authority (which is, I think, the FBI)
2. They investigate and pass the information to the relevant UK authority (the Metropolitan Police, I think)
3. They jointly investigate and if/when they have enough evidence, they make the arrest
4. The accused is extradited from the UK to the US
5. The person stands trial in the US

In practice, there are all sorts of reasons why one of these steps fails. Because police have discretion over what cases to pursue and limited resources, investigating scams rank behind things like terrorism, counter-espionage and drug and arms smuggling. Each individual scam is small (from the perspective of a country) and while it can be huge collectively (scamming is Nigeria’s second biggest export industry behind oil) its very hard to prosecute so quite often the complaint is taken and files and quietly dies.